# How to properly use pouchdb in Angular2 and Ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb

I am trying to convert to Angular 2 (Ionic2) and my app uses pouchDB.

In Angular1 I was using  `var _usersDatabase = pouchDB(CouchConstants.COUCHDB_USERS_DB_NAME);` with a lowercase pouchDB and no `new`. But the TypeScript compiler is complaining, so I did that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { UtilsService } from '../providers/utils-service';
import { MigrationService } from '../providers/migration-service';
import { CouchConstants } from '../couch-constants';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';




@Injectable()
export class UsersDatabase {



    constructor(
        private storageService: LocalStorageService
        , private UtilsService: UtilsService
        , private MigrationService: MigrationService

    ) {


    'use strict';


    var _usersDatabase = new PouchDB(CouchConstants.COUCHDB_USERS_DB_NAME);
    //We attach the function if necessary
    if (_usersDatabase.updateReplication == null) {
        _usersDatabase.updateReplication = function (newDocsIds) {
                    console.info("Updating replications with: ");
                    console.info(newDocsIds);
                    ...
```

but I get this error:

```
Typescript Error
Property 'updateReplication' does not exist on type 'Database<{}>'.
src/providers/users-database.ts
    //We attach the function if necessary
    if (_usersDatabase.updateReplication == null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

To import PouchDB in a TypeScript project, you need to do:

```
// Correct
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

rather than:

```
// Incorrect
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

Also I don't believe `updateReplication` is a supported PouchDB API, which is probably why you're seeing the TypeScript warning.

Comment: Nlawson in person, thanks, I changed the way I import pouchdb. And I edited the question to show that updateReplication is a custom method added to _usersDatabase, how can I code this to avoid this error:
`Typescript Error
Property 'updateReplication' does not exist on type 'Database<{}>'.`

Comment: And @nlawson, is the new required to declare pouchDB ? Because in angular1 I was not using it.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed PouchDB For Angular 2 + Typescript using the angular-cli. This is what I did and it works for me:

1. `ng new SOMENAME`
2. `npm install --save pouchdb`
3. `npm install --save-dev @types/pouchdb`
4. In your app.component `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';`
5. In your App Component Class `public db: any;` and to init `this.db = new PouchDB('test'); // , {storage:'persistent'} not working in typescript without updating typings`

see https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find/issues/201.

If you have problems installing the packages on windows with an EPERM Error use (f.e.) `npm install --save pouchdb --no-optional` to disable the warning. The installation should still be ok. For more info see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17671